# how to instantiate a listener by reflection in Android

Tags: java, android

I have to develop an application for Android 1.6 (API 4), which should be able to use the OnAudioFocusChangeListener (available since Android 2.2 - API 8) in the phones with Android 2.2 or later.

Anyone can tell me how to instantiate a listener by reflection?
I have already managed to run static and also non-static methods by reflection, but I don't know how to do with listeners.

This is the listener to reflect:

```
AudioManager  audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

OnAudioFocusChangeListener audioListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
    // code to execute
    }
};

public void getAudioFocus() {
    audioManager.requestAudioFocus(audioListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
}

public void releaseAudioFocus() {
    audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(audioListener);
}
```

This is a code example with methods I managed to run by reflection:

```
Class BluetoothAdapter = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter");
Method methodGetDefaultAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getMethod("getDefaultAdapter"); // static method from the BluetoothAdapter class returning a BluetoothAdapter object
Object bluetooth = methodGetDefaultAdapter.invoke(null);
Method methodGetState = bluetooth.getClass().getMethod("getState"); // non-static method executed from the BluetoothAdapter object (which I called "bluetooth") returning an int
int bluetoothState = (Integer) methodGetState.invoke(bluetooth);
```

Comment: Here is good example http://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/how_to_implement_an_interface

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end I solved it by using a Proxy class. Here is the code!

```
private AudioManager theAudioManager;
private Object myOnAudioFocusChangeListener = null;

private static final int AUDIOMANAGER_AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN = 1;
private static final int AUDIOMANAGER_AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS = -1;

theAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

// instantiating the OnAudioFocusChangeListener by reflection (as it only exists from Android 2.2 onwards)
// we use a Proxy class for implementing the listener
public void setOnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    Log.i(this, "setOnAudioFocusChangeListener()");
    Class<?>[] innerClasses = theAudioManager.getClass().getDeclaredClasses();
    for (Class<?> interfaze : innerClasses) {
        if (interfaze.getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("OnAudioFocusChangeListener")) {
            Class<?>[] classArray = new Class<?>[1];
            classArray[0] = interfaze;
            myOnAudioFocusChangeListener = Proxy.newProxyInstance(interfaze.getClassLoader(), classArray, new ProxyOnAudioFocusChangeListener());
        }
    }
}

// called by onResume
public void getAudioFocus() {
    if (myOnAudioFocusChangeListener != null) {
        Log.i(this, "getAudioFocus()");
        try {
            Method[] methods = theAudioManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
            for (Method method : methods) {
                if (method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("requestAudioFocus")) {
                    method.invoke(theAudioManager, myOnAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AUDIOMANAGER_AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
                    Log.i(this, "requestAudioFocus");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

// called by onPause
public void releaseAudioFocus() {
    if (myOnAudioFocusChangeListener != null) {
        Log.i(this, "releaseAudioFocus()");
        try {
            Method[] methods = theAudioManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
            for (Method method : methods) {
                if (method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("abandonAudioFocus"))
                    method.invoke(theAudioManager, myOnAudioFocusChangeListener);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**PROXY OnAudioFocusChangeListener class**

```
private class ProxyOnAudioFocusChangeListener implements InvocationHandler {

    // implements the method onAudioFocusChange from the OnAudioFocusChangeListener
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        Log.e(this, "onAudioFocusChange() focusChange = " + focusChange);
        if (focusChange == AUDIOMANAGER_AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
            Log.i(this, "AUDIOMANAGER_AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS");
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(ControllerHandler.SET_ON_PAUSE);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        } else if (focusChange == AUDIOMANAGER_AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
            Log.i(this, "AUDIOMANAGER_AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN");
            // no action is taken
        }
    }

    // implements the method invoke from the InvocationHandler interface
    // it intercepts the calls to the listener methods
    // in this case it redirects the onAudioFocusChange listener method to the OnAudioFocusChange proxy method
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        Object result = null;
        try {
            if (args != null) {
                if (method.getName().equals("onAudioFocusChange") && args[0] instanceof Integer) {
                    onAudioFocusChange((Integer) args[0]);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unexpected invocation exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO reflection will make your classes less readable. Also reflection is quite a bit slower then normal field or class access.

As an alternative see the wrapper class approach described here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/backward-compatibility-for-android.html

Create interface and two implementations of it, one for API 8+ and the other for the earlier versions. In your API8 class you can use API 8 classes including `OnAudioFocusChangeListener`. Then instantiate the version based on version of OS, which you can check via [`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT).

Comment: I am not completely sure I could use a wrapper, as I need to pass an `OnAudioFocusChangeListener` object as an argument to the `requestAudioFocus` and `abandonAudioFocus` methods of the `AudioManager` object. I suppose it doesn't work if a pass OnAudioFocusChangeListener wrapper instead.

Comment: You can have it as an inner class inside wrapper class. This would work.

Comment: I would also give the reflection a miss - it's code smell - especially when there's a better way to solve it.  Use the wrapper method - much nicer.

Comment: The wrapper method has the disadvantage of requiring the target sdk version to be set to the higher one. This means that you need to be careful that all classes available in the higher APIs don't get executed by devices with lower APIs. As eclipse (as far as I know) is not able to highlight which code is available only on higher APIs and needs to be "blocked" to lower APIs, it's easy to forget to recode for the lower APIs.
So, my suggestion it's to use reflection in case only one or two classes available in the higher APIs need to be used.

Comment: True, good point. But you can still make wrappers that include all version dependent code, one wrapper per version (or group of versions), then by simply switching target version in Eclipse, you see errors popping out in one place. This should make it easier to catch version-related errors.